# Как организовать Pre-receive Hooks на GitHub?

Tags: github

**Задача:**

Перед пушем на сервер нужно проверять код на соответствие psr стилю, если есть ошибки, пуш необходимо откинуть.
Естественно интересует проверка на сервере, так-как на клиенте это легко обходится и хуки нельзя обновить всем разработчикам.

---

После прочтения статей и копания, я понял, что это делается через хуки, в частности pre-receive. Однако, походу GitHub не поддерживает серверные хуки без энтерпрайз пакета.

Вопрос, можно как-то без энтерпрайз решить мой вопрос ?

П.С. репозиторий приватный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Можно.

- Сделать "главную" ветку (`master`?) защищённой (protected).
- Запретить разработчикам **прямые** пуши в эту ветку на уровне прав доступа в организации на GitHub, пусть вместо этого создают и принимают pull request'ы.
- Использовать для проверки стиля pull request'ов любой внешний сервис Continious Integration или аналогичный, в настройках отметить его обязательным (required). Таким образом, пока его проверка не будет "зелёной" (`"state": "success"` в API), принять PR будет нельзя (без прав администрирования).

  - Есть существующие сервисы, но они для приватных репозиториев стоят денег.
  - Можно такие проверки устраивать и на своём сервере, о новых коммитах узнавать через [вебхуки](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), а о статусе проверок сообщать с помощью [GitHub Status API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/).